# Objective-C: can initialize one class but not the other

Tags: objective-c, class, header, initialization

I have some objective-C code with a few classes. I'm trying to initialize each of the first two classes within the third class. One works fine, turns the right color in Xcode and allows me to jump to the definition. The other for some reason doesn't. I've poured over it but can't see what distinguishes the two.

MainClass.m:

```
#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"

@implementation MainClass

Class1 *class1 = [Class1 new];
Class2 *class2 = [Class2 new];

@end
```

Class1.h:

```
#ifndef Class1_h
#define Class1_h


@interface Class1 : NSObject

@end

#endif
```

Class2.h:

```
#ifndef Class2_h
#define Class2_h


@interface Class2 : NSObject

@end

#endif
```

There's no difference in header files of Class1.h and Class2.h. Both are imported into the MainClass.m But for some reason Class2 isn't recognized in MainClass.m, yields "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" on Build+Run and doesn't allow me to command-click and jump to the definition.

I'm not sure where to look at this point. I've copied and pasted the code from the Class1.m file into Class2.m only changing the `#import Class2.h` header import and `@implementation Class2` lines to make sure its not something in the .m files...problem persists.

Comment: You might have a lingering `#define` of `Class2_h` elsewhere. By the way, we don’t generally use that `#ifndef`/`#define` pattern in Objective-C.

Comment: and you need to define implemented methods (even init if you changed from inherted NSObject) in your interface so Xcode can scan the headers and jump to the right one.

Comment: It looks like the #import "Class2.h" in the mainClass.m wasn't working. Tried a few dozen suggested troubleshooting techniques and now everything seems to function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an apostrophe instead of a double-quote at the end of your second import.

Comment: yea sorry that was just a typo in the SO question

Answer (score 0):

You might have a lingering `#define` of `Class2_h` somewhere. (This can happen if you use this `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` pattern, especially if cutting and pasting code.)

---

For what it’s worth, you really don't need this `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` pattern around your `@interface` references. Often C programmers are used to using this pattern a lot, but it’s just not needed in Objective-C class definitions.

For example, consider scenario where `Class1` had a property that was a `Class2`:

```
//  Class1.h

#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
#import "Class2.h"

@interface Class1 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Class2 *class2;

@end
```

And

```
//  Class2.h

#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

@interface Class2 : NSObject

@end
```

Then `MainClass` can import both headers without incident (even though `Class1.h` currently imports `Class2.h` already):

```
//  MainClass.m

#import "MainClass.h"

#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"

@implementation MainClass

- (void)foo {
    Class1 *class1 = [Class1 new];
    Class2 *class2 = [Class2 new];

    NSLog(@"Class1: %@", class1);
    NSLog(@"Class2: %@", class2);
}

@end
```

You would have thought that this redundant `#import "Class2.h"` would cause problems, but it doesn’t. Objective-C tried to get us out of worrying about all of these `#define` references.

---

Now, that having been said, using that above example, `Class1.h` might not even `#import` the `Class2.h` file, at all, but it might just do a forward declaration of the class. And if `Class1` implementation needed to interact with `Class2` objects, you’d do the `#import` of `Class2.h` in `Class1.m`, not `Class1.h`:

```
//  Class1.h

#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

@class Class2;

@interface Class1 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Class2 *class2;

@end
```

But regardless, we just don't tend to use the `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` pattern in Objective-C.